# List<Integer> as a JRBeanCollectionDataSource to a Subreport, how to get the integer value display on the report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am passing a `List<Integer>` as a `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` to a `Subreport`, I was wondering how you retrieve the integer value and display on the report. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The integer value of what? The length of the list? Or is it a List<Integer> (i.e., list of int values)?

Comment: It is a list of int values. I need to get the value out of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the information you need to pass a list of Integers into a Japser Subreport here, and how to access it within the detail band:

http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=82063

Comment: Link not working. I have a similar problem. Is there anywhere else I can view the answer?